# delete row of a dataframe with a specific value

Tags: r, dataframe, delete-row

I have a dataframe (df) with 10 columns and more than 10000 rows, I want to delete all rows that contain the value -999, i guess thats simple, So i do:

```
dfnew=df[!rowSums(df ==-999),]
```

all my columns have the same number of elements (10950) and all my rows as well (10), but when i run this i get the error:

```
Error in Ops.data.frame(xyz, xyy[!rowSums(xyy == -999), ]) : 
  ‘==’ only defined for equally-sized data frames
```

this is the head of my dataframe:

```
3035 1989  4 25  0   32.8   25.8  0  0 26.2   0
3036 1989  4 26  0 -999.0   23.6  0  0  1.0   0
3037 1989  4 27  0   32.4   18.6  0  0  0.0   0
3038 1989  4 28  0   31.8   19.6  0  0  0.0   0
3039 1989  4 29  0   33.2   19.2  0  0  0.0   0
3040 1989  4 30  0   32.4   19.6  0  0  0.0   0
3041 1989  5  1  0   33.0   19.8  0  0  0.0   0
3042 1989  5  2  0   32.6   18.8  0  0  0.0   0
3043 1989  5  3  0   32.8   19.2  0  0  0.0   0
3044 1989  5  4  0 -999.0 -999.0  0  0  1.0   0
```

help!

Comment: Please check the output of `!rowSums(df ==-999)`. Also `str(df)` would be good starting place to know if the 'df' is indeed a data.frame or matrix

Comment: Perhaps `head` of that or `table` or ... perhaps not 10000 :-)

Comment: It should be `rowSums(df ==-999) > 0`.

Comment: For me `df <- data.frame(col1 = c(1, 2, -999), col2 = c(-999, 2, 3), col3 = c(1, 3, 4)); df[!rowSums(df ==-999),]` works

Comment: when i try my method with a small dataframe like akrun did it works, but not for mine

Comment: '#Rui Barradas when i try rowSums(df ==-999) > 0 i get a bunch of TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

Comment: @OscarMolina. What do you get with `!rowSums(df ==-999)`

Comment: #akrun i get: TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE... etc

Comment: okay, then i don't find an issue why the error happens.  Do you find any `NA` elements, try `df[!rowSums(df == -999, na.rm = TRUE),]`

Comment: #akrun same thing happens, because i dont have na values. what r does mean with "equally-sized data frames"?

Comment: i can't reeplicate this behavior `i1  <- !rowSums(df ==-999)` check the `lengtth(i1)` and `is.vector(i1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This filters all rows containing `-999`.

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  filter_all(all_vars(. !=-999))
```

Where `df` is a data frame. Make sure there is no `NA` in the rows otherwise  change the `filter_all` to `filter_all(all_vars(. !=-999 | is.na(.)))`.